# Which commission-free card options are available to UK residents who want to travel abroad?

Tags: international-travel, money, eu, forex-cards

I am traveling to Bangalore from Edinburgh via Dublin and Abu Dabhi.

The thing is I have got a good layover time in both Dublin and Abu Dabhi  and so I'm looking to do some shopping over there.

To be honest, Monzo sounds a pretty good deal, like one can withdraw money, do swiping without any extra charge in almost any country.

But I'm still on the waiting list for Monzo.

When I searched on internet, there are so many travel cards like Thomas Cook etc, but I could find none like Monzo so far.

I thought of buying local tickets but again it's a bit hassle as there are some limits to money that we can carry like that.

Can anybody suggest me the best travel card with pretty good deals and trust worthiness?

### Update

Basically I am looking for a travel card with below options

- A card that charges less or doesn't charge any fee for transactions and money withdrawals.
- A card that supports many currencies
- A card that works with many ATMs

Comment: I've been using an aa travel money card, which has been fine in most ATM's (about half the machines so far) in India, but I haven't used it for purchases as I think it charges extra for charges under £50. Can't say its the best, but it works.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Please find the updated question

Comment: I've updated the question to make it a bit more broad and not opinion based.

Comment: Note that many credit cards/banks only serve one country (or a specific list of countries), even within the EU. For example, N26 would seem to satisfy some of your requirements but is not available in the UK.

Comment: @Relaxed I've edited the post to make it more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all your prayers is [Revolut](https://www.revolut.com):

- The account is free
- All card transactions are free, regardless of the currency
- Unlike almost every other bank in the EU they use the interbank exchange rate for foreign currencies. Other banks usually have an exchange rate that is 2% worse than Revolut's.
- ATM withdrawals are free up to 200GBP/month, a 2% fee applies after that
- Their card indeed works with all ATMs that support MasterCard

The only caveat is that you have to sign up for a waiting list, so it may take a few weeks before you actually get the card in your mailbox.

Comment: What rate for foreign currencies do they use? They might not overcharge you but use a rate which is worse than 2% fee in other banks.

Comment: @Neusser fixed.

Comment: @Neusser Actually my earlier comment was wrong, the FAQ says Revolut uses the Spot Interbank rate (with some caveats for the Russian Ruble and the Thai Baht and a markup during the weekend).

Comment: I have started using Monzo and I find this to be satisfying my needs , one of my friend uses Revolut and he says it's great as well

Answer (score 4):

[Money Saving Expert](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/credit-cards/travel-credit-cards) has a good run down of commission-free cards available in the UK.

In particular,

- Halifax Clarity
- Barclaycard Platinum travel card (possibly only via a promotion)
- Aqua Reward
- Santander Zero

all meet your criteria.

1. They charge no fee at all for transactions and money withdrawals and use the VI~SA or Mastercard wholesale exchange rate.  (They are credit cards, so with the exception of the Barclaycard, they will charge interest from the moment of withdrawal, so it is worth paying them off immediately rather than waiting for the monthly bill.  If you do this they are free.)
2. They support 'all' currencies
3. They will be accepted widely as they are VISA or Mastercard.

Comment: I'd be careful using a credit card to get cash. The interest can be excessive and there are some wrinkles on how to pay it off completely. I would only do this by pre-loading a card, i.e. make a payment before you travel and never go into actual debt. This way, no interest accrues

Comment: @Hilmar, in general I agree.  In particular I would only use these cards for withdrawing cash and pre-load or pay off on the day.  I certainly wouldn't carry any debt on it.  The fee-free withdrawals are just so valuable that I think they are worth the exception.